# Unique count of terms aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to count distinct values of a field from my dataset. For example:

The `terms` aggregation gives me the number of occurences by `username`. I want to only count **unique** usernames, not all.

Here's my request:

```
POST appzz/messages/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "words": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "username"
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0,
   "from": 0
}
```

Is there a `unique` option or something like that?

Comment: So what's the verdict here? Seems like the proposal of @Jeffrey'jf'Lim  should be right (at least, that's my intuition). On the other hand, the `cardinality` seems to be experimental, and thus cannot be trusted :)

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the [cardinality aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) which was added in Elasticsearch 1.1. It allows you to request something like this:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
      "unique_users" : {
          "cardinality" : {
              "field" : "username"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i use the cardinality in URL?

Answer (score 2):

We had a long discussion about it with one of the ES guys in a recent Elasticsearch meetup we had here. The short answer is no, there isn't. And according to him it's not something to be expected soon.

One option to kind of do it is to get all the terms (give a really big size limit) and count how many terms are returned, but it's expensive and not really valid if you have a lot of unique terms.

Answer (score 1):

@DerMiggel: I tried using cardinality for my project. Surprising on my local system out of a total dump of some 2,00,000 documents, I tried the cardinality with precision_threshold of 100, 0 and 40,000(as the max value). The first two times, result was different(count of 175 and 184 respectively) and for 40,000 got out of memory exception. Also the computation time was huge as compared to other aggs. Hence I feel cardinality is not actually that correct and might crash your system when required high accuracy and precision.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still fairly new to ES, but if I get you correctly, it seems that you should be able to get your answer by simply counting the number of buckets returned in the response? (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

**NOTE**, though: *contrary* to what that doc says right now with size 0 ("It is possible to not limit the number of terms that are returned by setting size to 0."), my testing with the latest version (1.0.1 now) shows that this does not work! *On the contrary*, setting size to 0 will give you *0 buckets!!!* You should set (sigh) size to some arbitrary high figure instead for now if you want to get all the terms.

**EDIT**: whoops, my bad! I just reread the doc again, and only just noticed that version note there, and realized that this is only coming out in 1.1.0? That note is in the past tense ("Added in 1.1.0."), which is confusing, but I guess 1.1.0 hasn't been released yet....

Oh, and btw, there seems to be something wrong with your url? I hope you know that.